# Installing taggd jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to get [this](http://www.timseverien.nl/taggd/#items) plugin to work but i am a bit lost. I've linked to the javascript and css but Ive only managed to get a dot to appear on my page, I cant understand the instructions enough to get a message on them. Can I get any help with which code to put and where? Sorry if it is a stupid question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great plugin! To set a description of the taggd point you have to set the `text` option

> text: Optional. Set's the text of the popup. If omitted, there will be
>   no popup.

and set the setting `handlers` to show the hint on the images, like:

```
settings.push({
    align: {
        'y': 'bottom'
    },
    offset: {
        'top': -15
    },

        'handlers': {
        'mouseenter': 'show',
            'mouseleave': 'hide'
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/pHSje/